# Qt detecting Unicode command line arguments as question marks

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, command-line, arguments

Sometimes when I build a Qt C++ app (MinGW, Qt 5.7.0) and open it with arguments in Windows 10, it detects Unicode arguments as question marks. I don't really know when but I think it depends on parameter's length and being or not being whitespaces in parameter.

For example:

```
>app.exe سلام
receives: سلام

>app.exe سلاممممم
receives: سلاممممم

>app.exe سلامممممم
receives: ?????????

>app.exe d:\خطا
receives: d:\???

>app.exe "d:\خطا دار"
receives: d:\خطا دار

>app.exe C:\Users\Reza\Desktop\خطا.txt
receives: C:\Users\Reza\Desktop\???.txt

>app.exe C:\Users\Default\Desktop\خطا.txt
receives: C:\Users\Default\Desktop\خطا.txt
```

I tested using QCommandLineParser, and also app.arguments() but all had the same problem.

Comment: How do you print the output?

Comment: @vahancho It's only a demonstration. I surely know that QString contains ? instead of those characters, whether by comparing or showing in a message or opening the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem in MinGW compiler's globbing process. According to [QTBUG-84002](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-84002) and [MinGW Tips](https://www.willus.com/mingw/_globbing.shtml), it can be solved by adding this code above `main()` function:

```
extern int _CRT_glob = 0; /* 0 turns off globbing; 1 turns it on */
```